# Why does CreateFileMapping return "file already exists"?

Tags: delphi, winapi, shared-memory

I have an application which has a shared memory zone defined with `CreateFileMapping` and I am trying to read that memory from another application.

I tried this:

```
handle := CreateFileMapping($FFFFFFFF, nil, PAGE_READWRITE,
             0,$3200, pchar('FileMappingZone'));
```

But I get:

> Cannot create a file when that file already exists

What could be the problem?

Comment: Does your wrapper around winapi calls check `GetLastError` unconditionally after each call? It's expected for `CreateFileMapping` to return a valid handle **and** for the following `GetLastError` to return `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` (which is not actually an error if it's what you expect).

Comment: I call GetLastError just after the call on CreateFileMapping, if I close the application that has created the file mapping before it says : Operation completed succesefully

Comment: @opc0de Don't do that. Only call `GetLastError` when the documentation says to do so. And that is when `CreateFileMapping` returns `NULL`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `GetLastError` is supposed to be examined in non-error cases sometimes, unlike `errno`. But then it's important *not* to interpret its value as an error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not everything which sets `GetLastError()` value to non-success is an error. It's important to distinguish *errors* by function's return value first, and examine `GetLastError()` to get more information on the *kind of error* that happened.

For mappings that already exist, `CreateFileMapping` is documented to return a valid handle *and* to set `GetLastError()` value to `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`. In this case, error value is *informational*: it's valid to examine it if you're interested whether the mapping was existing before you opened it, but it's not an error. You detect *failure* by testing the return value for being NULL. Otherwise you just go ahead and use the handle.

P.S. If you want to ensure that the section exists before opening, you may use [`OpenFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366791(v=vs.85).aspx) which will fail for non-existing sections instead of creating a new one.

Comment: In this case, the sharing app would call `CreateFileMapping()` to share data and the reading app should use `OpenFileMapping()` instead of `CreateFileMapping()` to read the shared data. If `OpenFileMapping()` fails then the sharing app is not sharing any data (unless another error occurs, like the reading app not having permissions to access the sharing app's mapping). I would not have a reading app create the mapping if it does not already exist, unless it intends to share data of its own.

Comment: I would have a reading app create the mapping if I want them to be able to start in any order (and not wait/retry with possible races), which is sometimes important. OP's example provides a size for file mapping, so he obviously knows that other application intimately enough to make a decision.